# "point on the chart" or "point in the chart"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

There is a scatter plot with many points, referred to as "chart".

Which of the following is correct:

> Move the cursor over a point **in** the chart.

or

> Move the cursor over a point **on** the chart.

Comment: "Point **in** the chart" would be very rare, if used at all.  "**On** the chart" is far more idiomatic.

Comment: @hot-licks Thank you! I was confused because of the "_in_ the picture" / "_on_ the picture" thing.

Comment: Yeah, it can be confusing.

Comment: @HotLicks:  I was going to say that "point in the chart" sounds more natural to me.  I don't know how scientific this method is, but a google search of "point in the chart" (with quotes) gives 1,000,000 hits while "point on the chart" gives 770,000 hits.

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no accepted answer, I'll give it a try.

As a native speaker (from Canada), both sound perfectly normal to me and I've heard them used interchangeably.

Here is my take on why:

In a 3-dimentional space, "in" vs. "on" would change the meaning. For example, "on the box" means "on top", whereas "in" means "inside".

However, a screen is a 2-dimensional space. So "in the chart" means "inside the space occupied by the chart". And since you can't put anything "on top" of something else in a 2-dimentional space, "on the chart" ends up meaning the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a point 'in' the chart is clearer.  The cursor is 'on' the chart.

Comment: What evidence do you have for this assertion?