# Do I place the cursor 'in a cell' or 'on a cell' when working on a spreadsheet?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

This is about Microsoft Excel: I don't know, if I should say:

> Place the cursor **in cell** A5 or
>   Place the cursor **on cell** A5

or maybe something completely different?

I'd say "on" simply because Excel won't be in edit mode yet, so the cursor isn't flashing inside the cell. Does that make sense?

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/77386/

Comment: In your usage, informally both will be understood to be the same. More formally, the contents is **in** a cell, and the formatting is **on** a cell.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+cursor+in+cell%2Cthe+cursor+on+cell&year_start=1975&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20cursor%20in%20cell%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20cursor%20on%20cell%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Did you just move the cursor to the position of cell A5, or did you also click on it (which highlights the cell border)? Either would be described differently.

Comment: I single-clicked the cell, so, I moved the cursor to the cell using the mouse (instead of the arrow keys) There was this bold border around the cell, but the cursor wasn't flashing in the cell (the status bar says Ready).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd agree with you - except that "cursor" actually means the flashing thing. The bold border around the cell is called the "selection". So you should *actually* say "Select cell A5" - so that you can (for instance) say "Select cells A5:B7"

Answer (score 2):

Since, as John Burger said, the *cursor* **is** the flashing thing, it goes *in* the cell:

> Place the cursor in cell A5.

To achieve that, though, you click *on* the cell:

> Click on cell A5 to select it.